# IE9 is not rendering the borders of an element

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

I'm having an strange issue with some css and IE9.
I'm not sure but I can bet you is the first time you see it.

[image: Example Image]

All the three images are in a `div` with a class.
This is the CSS for the class:

```
.imagen_pro{
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    width: 180px; height:160px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
}

.imagen_pro img{
    max-width: 160px;
    max-height: 160px;
}
```

This is happening is some cases, i mean, not in every IE9 this is happening.
I don't know what's going on. If someone could help me i'd really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Hi all and thanks for answering. I've found what was going on. it happens that each one of this image are inside of an anchor tag and with that css the img  was overflowing the  so i had to apply some css to the  and make the div container a little taller. thank you anyway

Comment: can you show some actual HTML code?

Comment: What code do you have _between_ each image to separate them?

Comment: i think 2th element on those images can you give us HTML source or show us your page?

Comment: `width: 180px;` and  `max-width: 160px;` ?

Comment: Not sure but try setting display:block on the image.

Comment: Show your HTML, better yet, create a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Hi. thanks for answering. This is a joomla site. i didn't create it. I'm just updating it. You can take a look at the code at redsisusa.com. As i told you before, this is only happening in IE9, but not in every browser i've looked at. this is the very weird thing.

Comment: FYI this is the actual CSS code from the page: `.imagen_pro{border:1px solid #CCC; width:180px; height:160px; text-align:center; background-color:#FFFFFF;}` and `.imagen_pro img{ max-width:160px; max-height:160px;}`

Answer (score 2):

I'm betting that the pics are improperly positioned/sized. They're bigger than the max-size of you element (max-height: 160px;).
Use firebug, select the pics and fiddle with their height and position.

Also I see an error in you code. You have both :

> width: 180px;

and

> max-width: 160px;

These are contradictory statements.

Comment: Hi. thanks for answering. This is a joomla site. i didn't create it. I'm just updating it. You can take a look at the code at redsisusa.com. As i told you before, this is only happening in IE9, but not in every browser i've looked at. this is the very weird thing.  i've made a change in the code. i had a mistake in the previous one. Please take a look at the correct one

Comment: Hi all and thanks for answering. I've found what was going on. it happens that each one of this image are inside of an anchor tag and with that css the img  was overflowing the <a> so i had to apply some css to the <a> and make the div container a little taller. thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to reproduce your issue in my version of IE9. However, I would be willing to bet that the issue is that your images are popping out of the top or bottom of their container and are being drawn over the border.

Try adding `overflow:hidden` to the `.imagen_pro` class.

OR

If that doesn't work, either expand the height of the `.imagen_pro` to be, say 162px.

OR

Change the max-height on the images to be 1 or 2 pixels smaller. For example:

```
.imagen_pro img{
    max-width: 160px;
    max-height: 158px;
}
```

Comment: Hi all and thanks for answering. I've found what was going on. it happens that each one of this image are inside of an anchor tag and with that css the img  was overflowing the <a> so i had to apply some css to the <a> and make the div container a little taller. thank you anyway

Comment: So we were right and you didn't even give an up-vote or accept an answer? :(